# Is there a way of splitting a string in Processing without deleting the delimiter?

Tags: string, split, processing, delimiter

Here's my code:

```
String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

String [] abc1 = split(abc,b);

println (abc1);
```

...and for what it's worth here is what is printed:

```
[0] "a"
[1] "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Is it possible for the 'b' to be included in either of the split strings? I'm not an experienced programmer so any help greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for [String](http://processing.org/reference/String.html)'s [substring()](http://processing.org/reference/String_substring_.html) and [indexOf()](http://processing.org/reference/String_indexOf_.html) methods instead:

```
String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

println(abc.substring(0,abc.indexOf("b")));  //start to b
println(abc.substring(abc.indexOf("b")));    //b to end
```

Comment: ah thanks, that looks just the thing.. though I keep getting an 'out of bounds exception' and I can't figure out why

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The code I posted above works. Perhaps the indices you're passing to *substring()* are wrong in your particular situation. Can you post a snippet ?

Comment: Yes my code was as follows:                                          'println (abc.substring (1, abc.indexOf(9) ));'                       I think perhaps my mistake was writing an 'int' instead of a character?

Comment: I think you're misusing `indexOf()` which returns the index of the first found **character** you pass as an argument. If you're trying to get characters from 1 to 9 simply do `println (abc.substring (1, 9 ));`. Feel free to mark/vote if you find this acceptable :)

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to just add the 'b' back in.  You know what your delimiter is, and you know where it was, so you can manually re-add it:

```
for (int i=0; i<abc.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        abc[i] = 'b' + abc[i] + 'b';
    }
}
abc[0] = abc[0] + 'b';
abc[abc.length-1] = 'b' + abc[abc.length-1];
```

It's more orthodox to go with substring() and indexOf(), though.